# Execute or Run application with java Runtime() or Process Builder

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, runtime, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute applications from java `servlet`. When I run it on eclipse integrated tomcat its working fine. When I'm trying to do the same on os integrated tomcat server by deploying .war file into webapps, its not working. It doesn't encountering any error as well. Even I checked the logs, there is no error nothing but usual tomcat access log. Is there any other ways that I can execute applications like `firefox, chrome, gedit` etc.

Note: Basic bash commands like `ls, chmod, mkdir` were working. But while calling `gedit, firefox` like apps its not working.

Statements Used:
* `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`
  even `firefox` is called with `/bin/bash -c` as well. No result.
* `ProcessBuilder`

Any alternatives ??

Comment: Have you tried `waitFor()` and checking its return `int` value. Check the Error in `InputStream`, `OutputStream`  `ErrorStream`

Comment: yes I tried that one. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor()` . No change.

Comment: So whats the output of `waitFor()` and different `Stream`

Comment: @AnkitNigam Yeah its output is 0 and there is nothing in log. nothing but common tomcat log.

Comment: Do you run it on your local machine in the second case (_...on os integrated tomcat server..._)?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek . Its os integrated tomcat server...

Comment: @AdityaByreddy But is it on your local machine, or on a server?

Answer (score 2):

`ProcessBuilder` accepts multiple arguments, and you are supposed to split your command arguments. So if you're for example executing `ls -sl`, you have to call

```
 new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-sl");
```

Another example:

```
 new ProcessBuilder("pg_dump", "database", '-u', 'username', '--clean');
```

Otherwise ProcessBuilder might not recognise the command. Also don't forget to use

```
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);   // equivalent of 2>&1
```

Which will redirect stderr to stdout.